# Find and replace multiple different words

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find & replace 100 words from a list with their synonymous with one single command, for e.g. word "go" with "move", "love" with "romance", "distant" with "remote", "subject" with "matter" etc.

Comment: This is a good question (despite the downvote) but I suspect you will need to use VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) to write a script which can do this. I've added extra tags to your question in the hope it attracts some more constructive feedback than you've received so far.

Comment: How is this possibly a good question? Is it the non-existent example, the brevity of the request, or the lack of formatting that appeal to you?

Comment: Thanks Arkanon but can you tell be VBA script for this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tiny sample to get you started:

```
Sub xLator()
    from = Array("go", "love", "distant")
    too = Array("move", "romance", "remote")
    For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
        Cells.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:=too(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Naturally you would expand the translation arrays to meet your needs and perhaps restrict the range if that is a requirement.

**EDIT#1:**

Say *Sheet1* contains the data and *Sheet2* contains the translation table in columns **A** and **B.**  This macro will input the table and apply it.:

```
Sub xLator2()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Dim from(), too()
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1") '   contains the data
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2") '   contains the translation table

s2.Activate

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim from(1 To N)
    ReDim too(1 To N)
    For i = 1 To N
        from(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        too(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next i

s1.Activate

    For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
        Cells.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:=too(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Gary, can I find and replace more than 1000 words at a time, what is the limit?

Comment: @Sidharth 1000 words is easy.  If you have that many words, I would place the translation table in columns in a separate worksheet.

Comment: Can u please tell with example how to place translation table in columns in a separate worksheet, meanwhile I want to know the limit like if 1000 is easy then how much maximum can be take like 10000 or 15000 or what? Pls answer

Comment: @Sidharth If you are using columns to store the translation table, and if you are using a version of **Excel** 2007 or newer, then the limit would be 1,048,576 items.

Comment: Ok, but how to use columns to store the translation table, pls elaborate

Comment: Dear Gary, it works I am really very very very very very very thankful to you

Answer (score -1):

You're going to have to use Excel VBA to do this. Or, if you know Perl, you can read/write XLS files with Perl. Since I don't know Excel VBA I use Perl to do this.

Comment: Can you give me the script of perl which I can copy and paste to get the result & meantime guide how and where to paste it.